# Best way to model existing OCI infrastructure with Terraform

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Not sure if this question has been asked but I'm having some trouble finding a solution.  We have existing an existing infrastructure within OCI that has need been modeled with Terraform yet.  What is the best way to do this?  I've tried resource discovery however it's not giving me the terraform files that contain the compute instances or datasources, networks etc.  Just a bunch of blank terraform services files.  How can I go about modeling this infrastructure and all it's bells and whistles?  Does OCI have the ability to output the entire VCN as terraform?  Or will I need to go and model all of these things by hand and redeploy?

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Designer and Visualisation Toolkit (OKIT)** is a tool to design OCI environments in a nice web UI. One of its main functionality is the ability to query/introspect existing environments. It also let's you generate terraform script so I think it would answer your needs.

Alternatively it integrates with Resource Manager. Another nice feature is the documentation generation.

You can find it [here on github](https://github.com/oracle/oci-designer-toolkit). There are some links to useful blog posts to get started.

I personally start all my OCI deployments by drawing it in OKIT now.

*[Disclaimer] I'm an Oracle employee*